# Как получить данные?

Tags: comet, php

Привет. Хочу отправить данные на сервер с помощью формы.
Ответ приходит такой "$mm",а нужно строка которая отправилась с формы

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
  Здесь будет ответ сервера
 </div>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?>">
<input type="text"  name="txt" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
<?php
$txt=$_GET["txt"];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var comet = {
  connection   : false,
  iframediv    : false,

  initialize: function() {
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {

      // Для ие
      comet.connection = new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");
      comet.connection.open();
      comet.connection.write("<html>");
      comet.connection.write("<script>document.domain = '"+document.domain+"'");
      comet.connection.write("</html>");
      comet.connection.close();  
      comet.iframediv = comet.connection.createElement("div"); 
      comet.connection.appendChild(comet.iframediv);
      comet.connection.parentWindow.comet = comet;
      comet.iframediv.innerHTML = "<iframe id='comet_iframe' src='backend.php?l=<?php echo $txt ?>'></iframe>";

    } else {

      // Для фаера
      comet.connection = document.createElement('iframe');
      comet.connection.setAttribute('id',     'comet_iframe');
      with (comet.connection.style) {
        left       = top   = "-100px";
        height     = width = "1px";
        visibility = "hidden";
        display    = 'none';
      }
      comet.iframediv = document.createElement('iframe');
      comet.iframediv.setAttribute('src', 'backend.php?l=<?php echo $txt ?>');
      comet.connection.appendChild(comet.iframediv);
      document.body.appendChild(comet.connection);

    }
  },

  // эта функция будет вызываться ответами comet'а 
  printServerTime: function (time) {
    $("#content").html(time);
  },

  onUnload: function() {
    if (comet.connection) {
      comet.connection = false; // шоб не глючил эксплорер
    }
  }
}

$(window).load(function(){ comet.initialize(); });
$(window).unload(function(){ comet.onUnload(); });

</script>
```

файл backend.php

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
flush();

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Бэкэнд</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
$mm=$_GET['l'];
while(1) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'window.parent.comet.printServerTime("$mm");';
  echo '</script>';
  flush(); // посылаем данные клиенту
  sleep(1); // разгружаем процессор
}

?>
```

Интересует: данное решение будет успешно работать для чата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А с чего должна работать вот эта конструкция?

```
echo 'window.parent.comet.printServerTime("$mm");';
```

Давно ли стали обрабатываться переменные в одинарных кавычках?

И вопрос: нафига такие сложности вообще? Есть куча готовых реализаций чата. Плюс к этому уверен, что comet-соединения реализуются проще

Comment: Я опоздал уже:)

Comment: Бывает и такое :)

Comment: спасибо большое за внимание к теме.

Comment: @Photon У нас даже время публикации совпадает :)))

Answer (score 2):

Строки в php учили?

```
echo 'window.parent.comet.printServerTime("'.$mm.'");';
```

Comment: спасибо большое за внимание к теме.